# Async Controller Action Re-Called after one minute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an action on an MVC3 Async Controller which processes csv files, the async part of which is as follows:

```
  [HandleError]
  [NoAsyncTimeout]
  public void UploadAsync(int jobId)
  {
      var timestamp = DateTime.Now;
      Log.Debug("UploadAsync " + timestamp);

      var job = _fileUploadService.GetJob(jobId);

      Log.Debug("AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment " + timestamp);
      AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

      var task = Task<Job>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(90000);
      });

      task.ContinueWith(t =>
      {
         try 
         {
              AsyncManager.Parameters["Results"] = GetJobResultDetails(jobId);
          }
          //no "catch" block.  "Task" takes care of this for us.
          finally
          {
              AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
          }
      });
  }
```

and the completed counterpart is:

```
  public JsonResult UploadCompleted(int jobId)
  {
      Log.Debug("UploadCompleted");

      try
      {
          return AsyncManager.Parameters.ContainsKey("Results")
                     ? Json(AsyncManager.Parameters["Results"],
                                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
                     : Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ExceptionHelper.LogError(ex, Log, "message");
         return Json("");
      }
  }
```

This works fine when the ProcessJob(job) task takes less than a minute. After a minute, the same task is kicked off again on a separate thread, processing the same job as the one that is currently running.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing around timeout settings for either async controller methods or Tasks that might cause this behaviour?

EDIT-

I swapped the call to the process job for a thread.Sleep for a minute and a half and when I looked in the log I can see that the UploadAsync has still been called twice so it is nothing to do with the code that ProcessJob executes.

It is worth noting that this only happens when deployed to the integration server and not locally.

Could there be an IIS setting that needs upping to accomodate the longer process time?

EDIT -

UploadAsync called with Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#JobIdToProcess").text(@Model.JobIdToProcess);
    var jobId = $("#JobIdToProcess").text();

    if (jobId.charAt(0)) {
      process(jobId);
    }
});

function process(jobId) {
    alert("process called");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: makeUrl('~@string.Format("/{0}/{1}", "FileUpload", "Upload")' 
                                                          + "/" + jobId),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                xhr.abort();
            });
        },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var uploadResults = $.parseJSON(data);
            var completedDate = formatDate(uploadResults[0].CompletedDate);

            $("#CompletedDate" + jobId).html(completedDate);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "After a minute, the same task is kicked off again on a separate thread, processing the same job as the one that is currently running" ... I think you're going to have to share a bit more about this part of the process.

Comment: There can be several reasons for this behavior but it seems some other code timeouts (MVC default timeout is 45secs) and following the rules it has, calls the upload function with the believed next item (which is the current, unfinished one)

Comment: How are you calling the `UploadAsync` action from your view? Are you using AJAX? If so please show the corresponding code.