# Call MVC async action through Ajax, start task, send the ajax response before the task completes?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I have the following scenario:

I have an MVC Async Controller that has an upload action, which processes a csv file and saves the data to the database using nHibernate. This is called using

```
 Task<Nacr.Core.Entities.FileLoad.Job>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
            _fileUploadService.ProcessJob(job);
         }
});
```

Currently the action is called thorugh an ajax call, and I am waiting for the ProcessJob to finish before sending back my response to the originating ajax call.

I am notifiying the user of the files progress using a signalR notifier hub to populate a record count and progress bar on the UI, which works a treat. Therefore is no need for the ajax call to wait for this to complete, as the results are visible during processing.

However, if I close the ajax call after I have started the processJob running, I get the following error:

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed!
```

This is due to the fact that the Session is registered with a PerWebRequest lifestyle in Windsor, but my question is is there any way that the session can be used after the ajax call has had a response?

The reason for my question is that for very large files, the ajax request appears to be recalling the processJob after around a minute, presumably due to the fact that it has waited for too long without receiving a response for the original request.

My original question on this can be viewed here:
[Async Controller Action Re-Called after one minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215205/async-controller-action-re-called-after-one-minute)

Comment: Your problem is more of a castle-Windsor problem, not anything specific to MVC or nhiberbnate or even ajax.  I don't know much about castle-Windsor, but it sounds like you need to configure this particular injection to use a self-disposable resource.  Also, it's unclear if you really need an async controller here because you're not really synchronizing any requests if you just return right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the browser has not had a timely response from the MVC action and so automatically retries.

Look at the answer from this related question:
[What happens when no response is received for a request? I'm seeing retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302512/what-happens-when-no-response-is-received-for-a-request-im-seeing-retries)